# Can I use tables to contain my figures in word, while submitting it as a manuscript?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, writing, publishability

Because it is difficult to make a figure description stick to the figure in word (slightest motion of figure within the document messes-up a lot of text, especially near the figure) I decided to overcome the issue by making one-column-two-rows tables, and in top field I place the figure, and in the bottom field I place the figure's number and description. Figure contained in such box is much less rowdy.

I'm now considering submitting the article, but all the submission instructions for word documents (preferred by publisher) just say that:

1-figures should be numbered and described

No mention on how to actually do that. Will my approach result in problems? How to best number and label the figures?

Journals I'm considering are "Scientific Reports" and "Journal of Material Science"

Comment: I would ask an editor of those publications.

Comment: It used to be that figures were on separate pages (one page per figure) at the end of the submitted document. Then it is up to the production folks to put the figures in the "right" place later on. Check the submission instructions.

Comment: I see in the instructions for Journal of Material Science: "Supply all figures electronically. Authors are encouraged to embed their figures in the document near the paragraph in which they are first referenced." So, not separate (ignore previous comment). But, yes, I would use the table kludge to keep the figure and caption together...

Comment: When you say "in word," are you referring to Microsoft Word? If so, which version and what platform (operating system)? With my version of MS Word I can easily use the feature that it has for labeling figures so that the labels stay with the figures, but perhaps you're using a really old version or a different software title altogether.

Comment: Also, a screenshot might help, but then this turns into a question about software support and not academia, and it may be more appropriate on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Not that this is a microsoft word SE, but just to note that you can also make a one cell table and have word add a caption to the table, see eg https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-format-or-delete-captions-in-word-82fa82a4-f0f3-438f-a422-34bb5cef9c81